# Pass pointer as generic type c++ template

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I'm trying to pass a pointer (char*) to a generic function i wrote. But i get an error " Overloaded foo ambiguous in this context ". Why does this happen?

```
template <class T>
T foo(T a, T b)
{
    return a+b;
}
int main()
{
    char *c="Hello",*d="world";
    foo<char*>(c,d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really doubt that is the error. Please post an MCVE. But A) you can't add pointers and B) `char* = "string literal";` is deprecated. Use `const char*`.

Comment: Also note that `return a+b;` with `char*` might not do what you think it does. The result would be pretty useless.

Comment: There is no issue with the code except that you cant add pointers. Do you have another definition of `foo`?

Answer (score 0):

It have no reason to add two pointers, it result in a non-sensical pointer. Imagine e.g. that the first text is at address `0x7fffff00`, and the second one is in `0x80000100`. Then after an addition on 32-bit machine you going to get… `0`. Zero. Null pointer!

Perhaps you wanted to use string's instead, like:

```
#include <string>

template <class T>
T foo(T a, T b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{
    std::string c="Hello", d="world";
    foo(c,d);
    return 0;
}
```

Also note: in many cases *(like this one)* compiler can infer template type for you, so no reason to write it explicitly like `foo<std::string>(c,d)`.